# Chance of getting at least one 6 in a variable number of rolls of a die

Tags: probability

Consider the following experiment: You have five rolls of a die, but if you land a 1 you get an extra 5 rolls.

What's the chance of rolling at least one $6$?

My thought process is the following:

On average, you roll the die $30$ times ($1/(1-5\cdot\frac{1}{6})$), so the chance of at least one $6$ ought to be $$1-(5/6)^{30},$$
But this doesn't agree with the simulation I wrote to check it. This approach would work for a fixed number of rolls but since I'm working with an average I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the expected number of rolls as the number of tries to get a $6$.  First, to get so many rolls you need to roll $1$s, which are not $6$s.  Also, you have a fair chance to do five rolls with neither a $1$ nor a $6$, over $13\%$.

What you have to do is make a Markov chain.  Let $P(n)$ be the chance of getting a $6$ if you have $n$ rolls available.  The recurrence is $P(n)=\frac 16+\frac 23P(n-1)+\frac 16P(n+4)$  because you have $\frac 16$ chance to roll a $6$ and succeed, a $\frac 23$ chance to roll $2-5$ and have one less roll available, and $\frac 16$ chance to roll a $1$ and have $4$ more rolls available.

I made a simple relaxation in a spreadsheet.  I took $P(0)=0, P(n)=1$ for $n \ge 95$, a guess in between, and found $P(5)$ converged to about $0.83973$

Comment: Is there a way to find the exact value of $P(5)$?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated:  Not that I know of, or I would have done so.